# How to change PayPal button locale?

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-buttons

I am having problems with changing the language displated on the PayPal Button:

[PayPal Demo](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

When I add the following code, the language does not change (according to the documentation, it should change):

```
paypal.Buttons({
    locale: 'de_DE',
    style: {
       layout: 'vertical',
       color: 'gold',
       shape: 'pill',
       label: 'pay',
       tagline: false,
    },
    ...
})
```

But when I change it in the script, it does change:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD&locale=de_DE"></script>
```

How can I set the language by using Button configuration object and why it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> according to the documentation, it should change

Which documentation are you reading? Archived documentation for the older checkout.js?

---

The current PayPal Checkout documentation clearly states that if you need to set the button language to match your website language, [locale should be specified on the script/SDK line](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#locale).

But only do this if your website is in a specific language and you need it to match. Otherwise, the best language can be detected automatically.